# Get image from GET request and store it

Tags: ios, swift, image, closures

I'm working on an appli for get recipes.
I do my GET request to API, get the JSON, parsing it, all is good.
I get name, list of ingredients and an URL for the image, so I'm doing a request for my image but I don't know how to get her from closure.
I tryed to stock her in a propertie out of the closure but when i'm in the closure the propertie wasn't initialised. 
So I really don't know how to get out this image from closure.

Here's my code, thank you!

```
private func storeRecipes(for recipeData: RecipeResponse) {
    var image = UIImage()

    for recipe in recipeData.matches {
        let imageUrl = self.modifyUrl(recipe.smallImageUrls[0])

        self.getImage(for: imageUrl) { (data) in
            guard let imageData = data else {
                return
            }
            image = UIImage(data: imageData)!
        }
        let recipefinished = Recipe(name: recipe.recipeName, ingredients: recipe.ingredients, image: image)
        RecipesList.recipes.append(recipefinished)
    }
}

private func getImage(for url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping ((Data?) -> Void)) {
    let url = url

    Alamofire.request(url).responseData { (response) in
        guard response.result.isSuccess,
            let data = response.data else {
                completionHandler(nil)
                return
        }
        completionHandler(data)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the image returned as data from the api or a string referencing an url?

Comment: Did you include AlamofireImage  and instead of responseData  use responseImage?

Comment: I'm going to try with AlamofireImage, I didn't no!

Comment: Always the same problem. I get my image by AlamofireImage but I don't know how to store it, because if I do that in the closure it doesn't work and if I do that just after the closure I no longer have access to my image got by AlamofireImage :/

Comment: Nobody has a solution please?